# Perl system() command runs even after exiting the loop

Tags: perl

This is a simple Perl script which takes 2 parameters - a string (which is a URL) and an integer value.

All I am trying to do is to run curl requests on the passed URL for the given period of time (in seconds).

All's well when the URL is simple like `http://admin:admin@localhost:5074/?q=james` but the problem comes when there is `&` in the URL.

The problem is `system()` which make curl requests keeps running even after exiting the loop.

What's going on?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use URI::Escape;

my $url = uri_escape($ARGV[0]);
print "URL=".$url."\n"; 
my $duration = $ARGV[1];
print $duration;
my $start = time(); 
my $end = $start + $duration;
my $request = 0;

while(time() <= $end ){ 
    system("curl --user admin:admin --digest ".uri_unescape($url)); 
    $request++;
}

print "------------------------ END ----------------------------------\n";
print "URL = ".uri_unescape($url)." \n";
print "Total requests made = ".$request."\n";
print "Reqs/sec = ".($request/$duration)."/sec \n";
#print $start."\n";
#print $end."\n";
print "Duration = ".$duration." sec \n";
print "-------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
```

The command is:

```
perl curl.pl "http://admin:admin@localhost:5074/?q=james&format=xml" 5
```

Comment: Why not using  the glossy `WWW::Mechanize` or `LWP` module ?

Comment: I want to use native perl modules because I want to be able to run on any machine without having to deal with installing perl modules

Comment: It is never correct to pass an URL to `uri_unescape`. `uri_unescape` is used to unescape components between unescaped separators.

Comment: I've updated your question, including the title, to refer to `system()` rather than `System()`. Perl identifiers are case-sensitive; `System` could easily be some unrelated user-defined function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `&` character in your URL which is being interpreted by the shell as 'run this command in the background'. You need to escape metacharacters such as `&` properly to avoid having the shell interpret them, either via:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
system("curl --user admin:admin --digest " . shell_quote($url));
```

or the preferred:

```
system('curl', '--user', 'admin:admin', '--digest', $url);
```

The latter avoids creating a shell at all, and forks/execs `curl` directly with the given arguments, which are escaped automatically. It is faster and more secure. See the [system perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for more information.

As an aside, you should consider using [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent). It's part of the Perl core for newer Perls (no installation) and you don't need to worry about escaping anything.

Comment: Awesome! that works. Thanks a lot @rjh, sputnik, ikegami and Kieth. Appreciate your time.